# Mismatch between GPS points and data layer at high latitude

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, arctic

I am currently working on animal movement, based on GPS animal-attached device, at high latitude (north-east corner of Greenland, between 80° and 82° north).

I observe an important mismatch between some of the data (both shapefiles and rasters)I am using and satellite images. I can summarize this by grouping them in two categories :

When displayed again (for example) sentinel satellite imagery, data from MODIS dataset (MOD11, MOD29 and MODIS TERRA LST) do match the coastline from satellite imagery. MOD11 and MODIS TERRA LST CRS is WGS84, `EPSG:4326`, whereas MOD29 CRS is `EPSG:6931` (EASE Grid 2.0 North). The match with coastline is confirmed by consistent animal GPS location on the coast.

When displaying coastline from the GSHHG dataset (https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/), MASIE Sea Ice Extent (https://nsidc.org/data/g02186) or MASAM Sea Ice Concentration (https://nsidc.org/data/G10005), coastline DO NOT match with satellite imagery. MASIE and MASAM dataset CRS in proj4string format is `+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-80 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`, whereas GSHHG CRS is `EPSG:4326`.

Mismatch is shown in the middle and bottom screenshot shown here (top one shows matching raster).

[image: Top image shows data matching with satellite coastline. Middle and bottom images show the mismatch between data and satellite coastline.]

I used QGIS to display data and illustrate my problem, but I am pretty sure the problem does not come from "on-the-fly" projection since I encounter similar problem when displaying data with R, and data extraction (raster::extract function) does confirm the mismatch. It neither comes from the different resolutions of the datasets I am using.
Note that this mismatch only appears in this northeast corner of Greenland, for what I've observed.
I guess it might come from a difference in the projection method, since I have no other clue of what it could be.

Please, feel free to ask any further details.